# SQLite3 - Cannot Open Database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sqlite3.h"
int main()
{

    sqlite3* db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("testing.db",  &db);
    std::cout << rc << std::endl;
    std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    std::cin >> rc;
}
```

When I run it, the program outputs "21" and "library routine called out of sequence". What am I doing wrong? 21 is the code for SQLITE_MISUSE. See: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: Running Windows Vista x64 and compiling with Visual Studio 2008. I'll try and see if creating another solution does anything if the problem is not in the code.

Comment: Re-creating the solution fixed the problem, I really don't know how this was the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call sqlite3_errmsg() to get the actual error message.

**Edit:**
When I run your code, it returns 0. Seems to work fine here.

Which system are you running the code on? How was your code compiled?